Update single column with multiple values
I am trying to add multiple values at once in existing table using query
That column with NULL values "County" I want it populated with countries like Kenya, Uganda, Cameroon, Ghana.
I have successfully added only one county 'Tanzania' but I couldn't add all of them at once
How to modify
Update Madanga

Set County= 'Tanzania'

Where ID=1

So I can add all countries at once in above query

FYI, SQL Server 2008 reached end of life 5 years ago; it is long past time you should have upgraded your instance by now. Using such an old version is a severe security risk for you, your company and your users.

I don't know why your request got a downvote. Maybe it is because the requirement to do this in one statement seems a bit weird, because doing it in separate statement seems so straight forward, and you are not explaining why you think this must be done in one statement.

It is also uncommon for a table to have a column with country names (unless it is the country table itself, but then it would already contain the names). One would rather place a country ID here referencing the country table. To keep this short: This may be an xy problem, where you give us only few information and your solution to an underlying problem that we don't know of, and that original problem might benefit from a different solution altogether. What you may really be looking for could be one transaction or maybe an update from other tables or something entirely else.

On a side note: a country and a county are two different things.

You know how to set one country:
update madanga set county = 'Tanzania' where id = 1;

For reasons unknown to us, you want to set more than one country, but not in separate statements like one would expect.
update madanga set county = 'Tanzania' where id = 1;
update madanga set county = 'Kenya' where id = 2;

In order to do this in one statement you need a CASE expression:
update madanga 
set county = case when id = 1 then 'Tanzania' 
                  when id = 2 then 'Kenya'
                  else county
             end 
where id in (1, 2);

